# F5 or refresh does not trigger document.complete event in IE BHO

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, page-refresh, add-on, bho

I wrote one BHO file for my Internet Explorer Add-on. Refresh or pressing F5 does not trigger document.Complete event hence my content script does not get loaded.

How to execute my content script on pressing F5 using BHO.